# C# for each ITERATION

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Column formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283184/c-sharp-column-formatting)

well im in this tricky part of my code and is stuck for the time being so im asking for some help. I'm developing this in C# also. Here's piece of my code that the deals with it:
The method display is what im having trouble on the others are right. The problem output is wrong and has something to do with the for each loop. PLease take a look at the links of what my output looks like now and what im trying to make it look like please

```
thanks alot guys the question was answered
```

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I was looking for that post ;) ;)

Comment: Protip: Don't ask a duplicate question. You'll get blasted.

Comment: Still, use the original post to hash it out until it works the way you want.

Comment: In your other question (linked by @SimonWhitehead) you didn't ask about grouping the items by a certain criteria, just to present them in columns. And now he is asking for both grouping the items and present them in columns. I think you need to group your items as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971(v=vs.90).aspx and then present them with what you got in the answers of your previous question.

Comment: @AustinSmith You're still asking about the "words per line" issue though. Did you try my answer? Because you've just re-asked what my linked solution provided in an answer to this question..

Answer (score 1):

```
var max =
    (from pair in dictionary
    select pair.Value).Max()
for (int i = max; i > -1; i--)
{
    var items =
        from pair in dictionary
        where pair.Value == i
        select pair.Key;
    if (items.Count() > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWords occuring " + i.ToString() +" times");
        int count = 0;
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            if (count == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
            }
            Console.Write(item + "\t");
        }
    }   
}
```

Replacing the code in your `display` method with something similar to this should return the desired result.

Comment: thanks alot but now it looks like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/41895266.png/

Comment: @AustinSmith Hence, my use of the word similar. If you wish to apply more exact formatting do so, my goal was simply to point out that the reason it was writing incorrectly was placement of `Console.WriteLine("Words occuring " + i.ToString() +" times");` in your foreach loop.

Comment: @AustinSmith There that edit should apply the formatting you're looking for.

Comment: oh ok thank you very much I will continue to work on it to get the correct format but thanks for giving me an idea god bless you for your help

Comment: thank you again  it still doesnt get the right format I will continue to work on it to get the correct format but thanks for giving me an idea god bless you for your help

Comment: @AustinSmith What formatting are you referring to?

Comment: sorry not format necessarily i guess the output of what it should look like. Right now with the code above, the output turns out like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/507/89144856.png/ i have to adjust things in the code to make it look like this http://imageshack.us/a/img198/673/34382403.png sorry i said format if i confuse anyone wrong term to use in this case meant output

Comment: @AustinSmith I changed the `for` loop to count down from max rather than up to it to fix ordering and added a newline character to prevent writing on the same line as in your screen shot.

Comment: yeah I figured it out also thanks alot you don't know appreciative I am of you

Answer (score 1):

Following is the query to get the desired result

```
var dict = items.GroupBy(x=>x.Value).ToDictionary(y=> y.Key, y=> String.Join(" ", y.Select(z=>z.Key)));
```

To understand above query, refer [grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx), [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx), and [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx).

Following is your modified program

```
void Main()
    {

        SortedDictionary<string, int> dict =Words();
        display(dict);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static SortedDictionary<String, int> Words()
    {

        SortedDictionary<string, int> dic = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();

        String input = "today is Wednesday right and it sucks. today how are you are you a rabbit today";
        string[] word = Regex.Split(input, @"\s");

        foreach (string current in word)
        {
            string wordKey = current.ToLower();

            if (dic.ContainsKey(wordKey))
            {
                ++dic[wordKey];
            }
            else
            {
                dic.Add(wordKey, 1);
            }
        }
        return dic;
    }

    private static void display(SortedDictionary<string, int> dictionary)
    {

         var items = from pair in dictionary
                orderby pair.Value descending
                select pair;
        var dict = items.GroupBy(x=>x.Value).ToDictionary(y=> y.Key, y=> String.Join(" ", y.Select(z=>z.Key)));
          foreach (var item in dict)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Words occurung "+item.Key +" times");
             Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Value);
         }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The output

```
Words occurung 3 times 
today 
Words occurung 2 times 
are you 
Words occurung 1 times 
a and how is it rabbit right sucks. wednesday
```

Comment: wow thanks so much now the output looks like this http://imageshack.us/a/img198/3569/44164476.png do you happen to know how to put spaces so that only four words are on a line

Comment: Its a bit Tricky, You need to replace String.Join with something similar that puts a new Line for every nth (4th in this case) word.

Answer (score 0):

use .Distinct() in the select:

`var items = (from pair in dictionary order by pair.Value descending select pair).Distinct();`